# Problem during SQL Bulk Load

Tags: sql, database, windows-7, sqlxml, bulk-load

we've got a real confusing problem. We're trying to test an **SQL Bulk Load** using a little app we've written that passes in the datafile XML, the schema, and the SQL database connection string.

It's a very straight-forward app, here's the main part of the code:

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class();
objBL.ConnectionString = "provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SERVER\\SERVER; Database=Main;User Id=Username;Password=password;";
objBL.BulkLoad = true;
objBL.CheckConstraints = true;
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.xml";
objBL.KeepIdentity = false;
objBL.Execute("schema.xml", "data.xml");
```

As you can see, it's very simple but we're getting the following error from the library we're passing this stuff to: **Interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.dll**.

The message reads:

`Failure: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted`

We have no idea what's causing it or what it even means.

Before this we first had an error because SQLXML4.0 wasn't installed, so that was easy to fix. Then there was an error because it couldn't connect to the database (wrong connection string) - fixed. Now there's this and we are just baffled.

Thanks for any help. We're really scratching our heads!

Comment: Microsoft SQL. No idea what version, but we use 2008 software to interface with it. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this particular utility (Interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.dll), but have you checked that your XML validates to its schema .xsd file?  Perhaps the dll could have issues with loading the xml data file into memory structures if it is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

I try to understand your problem ,but i have more doubt in that,

If u have time try access the below link ,i think it will definitely useful for you
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know I did something that raised this error message once, but (as often happens) the problem ended up having nothing to do with the error message. Not much help, alas.

Some troubleshooting ideas: try to determine the actual SQL command being generated and submitted by the application to SQL Server (SQL Profiler should help here), and run it as "close" to the database as possible--from within SSMS, using SQLCMD, direct BCP call, whatever is appropriate. Detailing all tests you make and the results you get may help.