# Writing an XSD Schema to put XML data into SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, sqlxml

I hope someone can help me. I'm very new at this. I was wondering if it's possible to get an XSD Schema to dump XML data into *multiple* SQL tables (using the `sql:relation attribute`, etc.).

One table is proving no problems, so I just wondered if it's possible to dump data in two. It'd be nice to be able to do this with one XSD Schema, but do I have to make two passes on the XML for the second table?

Thanks for any assistance.

---

Here's the schema itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
<!-- Skimlinks/Everyfeed schema --> 

<!-- definition of simple elements --> 
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" sql:field="ProductName"/> 
<xs:element name="url" type="xs:string" sql:field="ProductURL"/> 
<xs:element name="image_url" type="xs:string" sql:field="ImageURL"/> 
<xs:element name="currency" type="xs:string" sql:field="currency"/>
<xs:element name="price" type="xs:string" sql:field="Price"/>
<xs:element name="merchant" type="xs:string" sql:field="Brand" default=" " /> 
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" sql:field="Description" default=" "/>
<xs:element name="item" type="xs:string" sql:field="Category" />

<!-- definition of attributes -->
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" sql:field="SKU" /> 

<!-- definition of complex elements -->
<xs:element name="category" sql:relation="ProductDataCategory">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="product" sql:relation="ProductData">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="title"/>
      <xs:element ref="url"/>
      <xs:element ref="image_url"/>
      <xs:element ref="currency"/>
      <xs:element ref="price"/>
      <xs:element ref="merchant"/>
      <xs:element ref="description"/>
      <xs:element ref="category"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="id" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="products" sql:is-constant="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="product" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="everyFeed" sql:is-constant="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="products" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Here's an example of the XML we're importing:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<feed version="2">
<numFound>7985</numFound>
<products>
    <product id="18639|216623247">
      <title>Trouser</title>
      <url>http://www.products.com/trousers/trouser/</url>
      <image_url>http://www.images.co.uk/images/big/4d624426.jpg</image_url>
      <verified_image>True</verified_image>
      <currency>GBP</currency>
      <price>1000</price>
      <prev_price>1000</prev_price>
      <firstseen>2010-10-27T00:00:00Z</firstseen>
      <lastseen>2010-10-27T00:00:00Z</lastseen>
      <merchant id="20748">Yours Clothing</merchant>
      <by>Yours Clothing</by>
      <description></description>
      <category>
        <item id="9">Lounge &amp; nightwear</item>
        <item id="3">Women</item>
        <item id="2">Clothing</item>
        <item id="1">Clothing, shoes &amp; accessories</item>
      </category>
    </product>
</products>
</feed>
```

As you can see, it attempts to dump into two tables: **ProductData** and **ProductDataCategory**. Only the stuff stored in the `<item>` elements should go in the latter table (in the field category).

The **error message** reads:

> Error: Relationship expected on 'category'

I don't know why :(

Thanks for any assistance in getting this working!

Comment: @Django - I've retagged because this is a Microsoft-specific extension to XML schema

Comment: You'll want to give more detail on what you're trying to do. How are you using this schema to bulk-load data into a single table?

Comment: Hi John, here's more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373104/problem-during-sql-bulk-load

Comment: @John, I've also added more detail to the original question.

Comment: Can you show what the ProductData and ProductDataCategories tables look like? Just keys will be sufficient. I suspect you don't have a foreign key constraint defined between the two.

Comment: Both tables are connected by their Primary Keys. There aren't any other keys, though.

Comment: Did you mean fields? If so, all the fields are listed in the "Simple Elements" in the sql:field sections. All belong to the table ProductData, apart from the last one, Category, which belongs to the ProductDataCategories table. The two tables are connected by a non-nullable int PrimaryKey called "ProductID". Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define a SQL relationship in the XSD file if you are trying to do a bulk import.  I ran into a similar problem (this is just an example, not specific to your XSD):

```
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <sql:relationship name="Detail"
                        parent="Product"
                        parent-key="ProductID"
                        child="Details"
                        child-key="ProductID" 
                        />
      <sql:relationship name="ProductFiles"
                       parent="Product"
                       parent-key="ProductID"
                       child="Files"
                       child-key="ProductID" 
                        />
      <sql:relationship name="ProductToList"
                        parent="Product"
                        parent-key="ProductID"
                        child="ProductList"
                        child-key="ProductID"
                        />
      <sql:relationship name="ListToProduct"
                        parent="ProductList"
                        parent-key="ID"
                        child="ProductListProduct"
                        child-key="ProductListID"
                        />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My XSD schema file already defines SQL relationships... although apparently not well enough. Do you have any further specific information how it could be fixed?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it in the doc you posted.  Not sure what else could be causing it as the issue I had corrected after I defined the relationships.  GL!

Answer (score 1):

Django,

Why not try something like DBVis - http://www.dbvis.com/ - to create a visual representation of all the relationships in your database and work towards having the xsd match the generated diagram. This'll ensure you get all of these relationships.

See here for an example screeshot for a very simple database - http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/doc/main/doc/ug/databaseExplorer/images/genericschemaview.png

I can vouch for it working well for much larger databases too.

Hopefully this'll help.